# Circles with dividers in css

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to implement this using [image]css? I have created a circle but the divider part is where I got struck

Comment: Pseudoelements `::before` and `::after` are your friend in this case. It's pretty simple to make it. Have you tried yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A linear gradient background

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, grey, grey 48%, transparent 48%, transparent 52%, grey 52%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be use this simple trick.

Hope this help.

Let me know further clarification.

```css
.circle {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: green;
    border-radius: 50%;
        position: relative;
}
.circle:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 3px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-66deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-66deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-66deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-66deg);
    transform: rotate(-66deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks..I never thought of using before and after.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another syntax with gradient:

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin:auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: 
   linear-gradient(grey, grey) left,
   linear-gradient(grey, grey) right;
  background-size:calc(50% - 3px) 100%; /*change the 3px to adjust distance*/
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  transform:rotate(-45deg); /*change the deg to adjust rotation*/
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```